# pass picture from usercontrol to Form

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a main form with 1 panel,
the panel has 10 user controls and
every user control has on picture box.

Main form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{

    Picturebox1.Image=....

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        uscontrol a=new uscontrol()
        {
            usimage=Image.Fromfile....  
        };
        panel1.Controls.Add(a);
    }
}
```

User control:

```
public Image usimage
    {
        get { return imagebox.Image; }
        set { imagebox.Image = value; }
    }
```

How can I do that when I click on one of the user controls, it passes image of that user control to main form and shows it in Picturebox1,
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to add `MouseClickEvent` to every `uscontrol`. To achieve that, edit your `Form1_Load` to this.

```
Picturebox1.Image=....
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    uscontrol a=new uscontrol()
    {
        usimage=Image.Fromfile....  
    };
    a.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(USControl_Clicked); //Note this added line 
    panel1.Controls.Add(a);
}
```

And then you will need to add `USControl_Clicked` to your `From1` code.

```
private void USControl_Clicked(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Here we cast sender to your uscontrol class and access usimage
    Picturebox1.Image = (sender as uscontrol).usimage; 
}
```